# How do I get XCode to run my react-native project with NODE_ENV == 'production'

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native

Is there a way to get XCode to set NODE_ENV == 'production' when debugging on device?

I'm getting errors, lots of socket connections errors, etc and want to know if it's related to my 'development' setup which should get filtered out when I run in NODE_ENV == 'production'.

This is one of the errors I'm talking about:

```
2016-09-21 16:24:34.757382 myApp[1730:374089] [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 5 Connection has no connected handler
```

What command does XCode run to launch the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that your system has the same issue I described in this medium post: https://medium.com/@alberto.schiabel/react-native-on-xcode-beta-8-0-how-to-fix-initial-build-error-f0225c649850

Comment: Thanks @Alberto, I ran into that problem last week and was able to get past it. My problem now is that when I run the project on device, the XCode debug window keeps giving me errors like this: 2016-09-21 16:24:36.249517 myApp[1730:374087] [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 6 Connection has no connected handler

Comment: I suppose you are jaggerwang?
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10027

Comment: Also did you try building the app in release mode?

Edit scheme >Select Run tab > Select Info tab > Change Build Configuration to Release > Build and run project